# How do I get all the <li> elements within a <div> having a specific id?

Tags: jquery

Seems simple enough and I think I've done it before once or twice. What is the jQuery selector syntax for grabbing all the `<li>` elements inside a `<div>` with id "chapters"?

I can get the `<li>` elements with `$('li')` and the div with `$('#chapters')` but I need to limit the selection to `<li>` within that div.

Here is the markup, followed by the jQuery selector. It doesn't work and now I'm at a loss as to why:

```
<li>1 - outside the div</li>

<div id="chapters">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</div>

<li>2 - outside the div</li>
```

JQuery selector:

```
$('#chapters li').css("background-color","red");
```

Comment: Regarding your update. Make sure you put the code in the `document.ready` callback, e.g. `$(function(){/* your code here */});` and provide valid markup. `li` elements outside `ul` or `ol` are not allowed.

Comment: @Felix: Everything was in the callback. A typo got me. Thanks!

Comment: Alternatively, you can make this selection using pure css: `#chapters li {/* write here your css code*/}`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is simply

```
$('#chapters li')
```

Have a look at the [**selectors** documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: No comma? When do you separate the selectors with a comma? Thanks for the link but at the moment I can't access that specific page.

Comment: @Special: I currently cannot access the page either... you use a comma if you want the union of the elements. E.g. `$('#chapters, li')` selects the `div` **and** *all* `li` elements. `$('#chapters li')` just selects the `li` elements *inside* the `div`.

Comment: @FelixKling: i am not sure how it worked. OP has  `chapters ` as classname and not id. id selector should not work ryte??

Comment: @Milind: Yes, the code example does not fit the description (OP says they have an element with *ID* "chapters"). If they use indeed `class`, it won't work.

Comment: @FelixKling: will change the classname to id then :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use Period(`.`) instead of (`#`) in the selector. Below is the code:

```
$('.chapters li').css("background-color","red");
```

Comment: that would refer to a class not an id